# Why "add Push notification feature to your app id" warning even after push-notification showing enabled in App ID?

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I am using Xcode8, swift 3, iOS 10

In Targets -> capabilities showing "add the Push notification feature to your app id".

I check my APP ID and it is showing pushnotfication enabled in both development and distribution.

With same APP IS and certificate I am getting notification in iOS9 but in iOS 10 i am getting error

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3000 "no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=no valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application}
```

and also showing red mark (issue)

Comment: @Anbu suggested answer is not according to question asked, my question is for Xcode8 and swift 3 testing on iOS10

Answer (score 119):

I restarted XCode and it was gone :-)

Comment: LoL... And yeah sadly, this is the correct answer. Probably a Clean would work too.

Comment: I am singing 'sad but true' \m/

Comment: I did clean>>build>>restarted XCode and it was gone.

Comment: This is hilarious :)

Comment: After spending several hours revoking and recreating provisioning profiles on developer.apple.com, this worked.  FU xcode

Answer (score 14):

Close Xcode -> reopen -> clean -> build -> run.

Fixed the issue for me. Xcode 9.0.

Answer (score 11):

Sadly I quit xcode then installed the .mobileprovision (double clicking it) then restarted xcode and the warning was gone...Followed the other answer here by SteMa

Comment: In what way is that an answer to the question?

Comment: Quitting Xcode and installing .mobileprovision, then restarting Xcode will solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me. For some reason xCode signed me out. 
The fix: 
Tap Xcode (top bar) -> select Preferences -> select your Apple Id -> Sign-in.
Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 7):

In my case it does not help restarting xcode again.

I just restart system and that problem was gone.

Comment: Yup, for those of who restarted XCode and still didnt get it fixed, restarting the pc works.

Answer (score 5):

After I enabled push for my app, I had to regenerate my provisioning profiles and re-download them for Xcode to recognized the aps attribute.

Comment: Can you please provide an example for what you did? From where would I regenerate my provisioning profiles and from where to re-dowload them and where to put them after download? I'm very new to xCode.

Comment: @Ionut you have to regenerate the provisioning profile in the https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/production of your account after you enable push for your app. You then re-download the profile and add it to Xcode in your app signing section.

Answer (score 3):

In my situation I went to here [image] & here [image]

under the general tab in xCode settings and reset my bundle identifier to a different name and it fixed the certificates and everything worked!

Obviously if you need the same bundle identifier you will need to go with some of the other suggestions here, but use this if all else fails.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, none of the above answers worked. I had to generate new certificates. Xcode >> Preferences... >> Accounts >> *select team* >> Manage Certificates... >> + >> iOS Development >> *repeat* + >> iOS App Store.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have enabled Push notification ,your old Provisioning profile become inactive . Edit that old Provisioning profile and download  fresh one , then try to generate  the   build .

Answer (score 0):

Check Info.plist -> Bundle identifier and establish it as YourProject -> Targets -> General -> Bundle identifier. Work for me

Answer (score 0):

Change your developer account in Xcode, because of APNS certificates developer account and Xcode developer account must be same.

--> Go to Target

--> Go to General Tab

--> GO to Signing

--> Select Team, Which account you used to develop **APNS certificates.**